# excel dynamically summarize a text matrix?

Tags: excel, summarize

So not sure quite what I'm asking here, but seeing if you could give me pointers? Let's say I've got a planning table like this below. I'm trying to think of a way to have a second table that will list each ToolID and a single cell that shows all the 'items' that have X for them, dynamically.

> Tool ID      A    B   C   D
>
> Group1    x   x   x   x
>
> Group2            x   x
>
> Group3            x   x
>
> Group4            x   x
>
> Group5                x
>
> Group6    x   x   x   x

So here's what the final output would look like

> Tool id   Items
>
> Group1    A,B,C,D
>
> Group2    A,B
>
> Group3    A,B
>
> Group4    A,B
>
> Group5    A
>
> Group6    A,B,C,D

I'm trying to think of a way to do this dynamically, rather than spending time writing a long concatenate or vlookup for each column, because the matrix is 
 ~100 rows and ~100 columns, so hand writing one big concatenation formula seems daunting.

Answer (score 0):

If your first table was on sheet1 and second on sheet2 B2 on sheet2 would be

```
=If(vlookup($A2,sheet1!'$A$2:$E$7,match(B$1,sheet1!'$A$1:$E$5,0),0)="x",B$1,"")
```

If your x was upper case change it above to "X"

Copy and paste this in every cell you want a letter on you table

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TEXTJOIN` if you have Excel 2016:

```
{=TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(B2:E2="x",$B$1:$E$1,""))}
```

To activate this formula use: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]